# How can I determine the JavaScript Engine from .js code?

Tags: javascript, v8, spidermonkey, javascript-engine, chakra

Is there a way using JavaScript code to know what JavaScript Engine, is the one on which that code is run on?

I don't want to get the browser type just the JavaScript engine.

Comment: Why do you require this? Perhaps there is another way to solve your problem.

Comment: As in, the name of the engine? In that case, can you define the set of names which you'd like to identify?

Comment: @Asad There is: get the browser-type and determine with a table who's who, but it will not work for an html5 application.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Why wouldn't that work for an HTML5 application?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes the name of the engine, I don't know what to expect... I need a way to get it without expecting some particular ones

Comment: Once again, unless the purpose of your application specifically encompasses detecting the browser it is run on, there is no need to do this. You can manage compatibility concerns with feature detection.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Maybe the developers of the Web Runtime will not build it entirely on a browser and put a different engine. Don't know.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu If you don't know what name you could expect, then what could you do with that name anyway?

Comment: @Asad Mainly I need to know if it is an V8 engine but knowing also if other would be better

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu OK, so you want to detect V8... (for a start)

Comment: Also it would be useful to have something that would give a result if run also on browserless based on V8 engine like nodejs, silkjs, or even pyV8

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes that would be great

Comment: At the end of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768595/1726343) answer you can find the information you need. Don't use it.

Comment: function javaEnabled() {
    [native code]
} is given also in spidermonkey

Comment: @Asad Now I know is not V8 what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How can I detect which javascript engine (v8 or JSC) is used at runtime in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768474/how-can-i-detect-which-javascript-engine-v8-or-jsc-is-used-at-runtime-in-andro/6768595#6768595) for some JavaScript code that uses feature detection to determine the platform.

Also:

> I think the better question is: Why do you care? You're basically
>   falling into the "browser detection" trap that a lot of people fell
>   into in the late 90's / early 00's. Since then, though, we've learned
>   that it's feature detection that's the more useful approach, not least
>   because the features supported in a given browser were (mostly) a
>   moving target. There's code now, running on IE9 with its
>   dramatically-improved DOM and JavaScript support, that's not using
>   those features because it's doing browser detection and falling back
>   on IE6 techniques.

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768595/1183010

Comment: I have many motives to want to do that, but also from curiosity. One of the reasons are web-runtimes that many mobile OSs suporting HTML5 have. I can automate deploying an app that queries the JS-engine and have a know what's new under the hood.

Comment: In that case, there is some code http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768595/1183010 to detect the engine (if you insist)