# Javascript : Identify whether it is a desktop Linux or Android

Tags: javascript, android, linux

Unable to identify whether it is a linux desktop machine or an android device using `navigator.userAgent` or `navigator.platform` as some android device's have the string `linux` in both. Details follows

```
Device                           OS               navigator.platform  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung Galaxy S3                Android 4.3      Linux armv7l
HTC One                          Android 4.4.2    Linux armv7l
Sony Xperia Z                    Android 4.2.2    Linux armv7l
Motorola Moto G                  Android 4.4.2    Linux armv7l
Samsung Galaxy Tab 3             Android 4.2.2    Linux i686
Nexus 10                         Android 4.4.2    Linux armv7l
Lenovo Yoga                      Android 4.2.2    Linux armv7l
```

`navigator.userAgent`

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; SCH-I800 Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Even I tried with touch events, but linux desktop can have touch or it can emulate touch. please help

**Update**: The solution should detect Linux even if Desktop browser's emulate device is active. [View Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068052/phonegap-detect-if-running-on-desktop-browser/29818615#29818615)

Comment: May I ask which problem you are trying to solve? Depending on the case, there might be other solutions than detecting the device based on the user agent.

Comment: Yeah you generally shouldn't have code that depends on the user agent... instead, it's much better to check for the feature that you want in the browser. http://modernizr.com/ is a great free library for just that.

Comment: I am working with cordova and the cordova files should be included only in the device not in desktop browser not even in the emulate option available in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
   // it's andorid
} else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/linux/i)) {
   // it's linux
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but fails on using the emulate option in the desktop browser and why is it required to match `linux` on the first line?

Comment: @lal actually you can skip that check.

Answer (score 2):

[Browser identification based on detecting the user agent string is unreliable and is not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

Nowadays browser detection is not a good practice, instead people use feature detection based on javascript or @media queries.

I recommend to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768595/3052862), maybe you can see the problem from another point of view.